# Making a instance variable a clickable direct link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In my app a user can create a post that has a link to a given website.
Example..
post.title -> I use this site to research topics.
post.link -> google.com

In post.show I would like to have a direct link to google.com

I try to do it simply with this:

```
<p><%= link_to @post.link%></p>
```

I need the link to route the user to google.com. However, it routes the user to

```
/topics/12/posts/www.google.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're missing `http://` on the Post's `link` attribute. When saving the record, you could check that the `link` string starts with `http://` or `https://` and if it doesn't, prepend the string accordingly.

Update:

Add a callback to your Post model:

```
before_save :prepend_link
```

Add a private method to your Post model:

```
private
  def prepend_link
    self.link = "http://#{link}" unless link.starts_with?('http://', 'https://')
  end
```

Use this in your view:

```
<%= link_to @post.link, @post.link %>
```

Comment: Yes that did work. Any recommendations on how I can check and/or prepend the string accordingly?

Comment: So even when I save the link as https://www.google.com, it does not work in production. It doesn't route anywhere.

Comment: That does work effectively for making sure the link is accurate. However, in production, even when the link is:
    https:// www.google.com/ 
, it does not work correctly. The page just flashes and doesn't route you anywhere.

Comment: If it works in development but not production there must be something else going on. Do you have your code on Github/Bitbucket or somewhere we could view it?

Comment: Ya sure. Here is the GitHub Repot. https://github.com/fresh5447/Bloccit. When looking at the views, make sure you look at the post files that are nested directly under topics.

Comment: I don't see the updates to the Post model that check for the `http://` at the beginning of the link. Did you push those changes to your remote repository on Github?

Comment: Yes, sorry I hadn't pushed yet, but it is current now.

Comment: It is working now. I updated my view to:
`<%= link_to @post.link, @post.link %>`
Whereas previously I left it as `<%= link_to @post.link %>`